How to implement windows custom credential provider using custom authentication logic?
My Custom credential provider is being invoked and redirects to windows homepage if the password matches the set-up password in Windows sign-in options.
But I want to authenticate with custom logic and if successful it will redirect to the Windows homepage. Is it possible?
For example, GetSerialization method is given below.
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetSerialization(_Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE *pcpgsr,
                                            _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION *pcpcs,
                                            _Outptr_result_maybenull_ PWSTR *ppwszOptionalStatusText,
                                            _Out_ CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon)
{
    HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
    *pcpgsr = CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED;
    *ppwszOptionalStatusText = nullptr;
    *pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = CPSI_NONE;
    ZeroMemory(pcpcs, sizeof(*pcpcs));

    
    if (_fIsLocalUser)
    {
        PWSTR pwzProtectedPassword;
        hr = ProtectIfNecessaryAndCopyPassword(_rgFieldStrings[SFI_PASSWORD], _cpus, &pwzProtectedPassword);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            PWSTR pszDomain;
            PWSTR pszUsername;
            hr = SplitDomainAndUsername(_pszQualifiedUserName, &pszDomain, &pszUsername);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                KERB_INTERACTIVE_UNLOCK_LOGON kiul;
                hr = KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonInit(pszDomain, pszUsername, pwzProtectedPassword, _cpus, &kiul);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    
                    hr = KerbInteractiveUnlockLogonPack(kiul, &pcpcs->rgbSerialization, &pcpcs->cbSerialization);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        ULONG ulAuthPackage;
                        hr = RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(&ulAuthPackage);
                        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                        {
                            pcpcs->ulAuthenticationPackage = ulAuthPackage;
                            pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider = CLSID_CSample;
                            
                            *pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
                        }
                    }
                }
                CoTaskMemFree(pszDomain);
                CoTaskMemFree(pszUsername);
            }
            CoTaskMemFree(pwzProtectedPassword);
        }
    }

I am expecting User will provide credentials to my custom credential provider and user will be authenticated by custom logic. And if authentication is successful then it will be redirected to windows homepage.
